# tar (child): test.zip: Cannot open: Is a directory when zipping node_modules

Tags: linux, docker, gzip, tar

I am running the command 
`tar -zcf node_modules.zip node_modules` to try zip up my node modules however get the error `tar (child): node_modules.zip: Cannot open: Is a directory` whenever I do. Note this works fine locally on my Macbook and on Ubuntu, but fails when running in a docker container. Any ideas?

Comment: Using a .zip extension for a tar file is going to be confusing.

Comment: What docker image are you running this in? It's possible that it's using a `tar` version that's not one of the common ones (for example busybox `tar`).

Comment: it's using the lts node release.

Comment: Can you include the whole Dockerfile in your question?  (Why do you want to create a tar file of the `node_modules` directory?)

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/2d82f7b12b855d3ce857f09efcf2c5508f0fe26b/14/stretch/Dockerfile I believe it's this one. I'm running a ci pipeline using concourse and need to pass node_modules between containers by uploading it to s3 and passing that down to each container(job) within concourse.